# Enable button on click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 4 buttons and I want to disabled them if some one is clicked

Note: Only one can be disabled at a time

So my logic is like:

In `btn1` Click event I do:

```
btn1.Enabled = false;
btn2.Enabled = true;
btn3.Enabled = true;
btn4.Enabled = true;
```

In `btn2` click event:

```
btn1.Enabled = true;
btn2.Enabled = false;
btn3.Enabled = true;
btn4.Enabled = true;
```

And same for other 2 buttons. When I see this code I don't like it so much. Is there any way todo something more readable and short to do this type of actions

Comment: Looks like you want a set of radio buttons rather than normal buttons.

Comment: I want functionallity like radio buttons, but I want normal buttons to show in form @DavidG

Comment: Then use radio buttons and set the `Appearance` property to `Button`

Comment: As @DavidG pointed out, this might help
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.appearance?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Problem is radio button you can change widt propert @DavidG

Comment: You can or you can't?

Comment: I can’t sorry @DavidG

Comment: What makes you think you can't?

Comment: You could also add these buttons under a panel. Disable all buttons through a function and then just enable the one the user clicks on. 

    foreach (Control ctrl in panel.Controls)
    {
        ctrl.Enabled = false;
    }            
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than write lots of code, it's much simpler to use a [`RadioButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton?view=netframework-4.8) group and set the [`Appearance`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.appearance?view=netframework-4.8) property to [`Button`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.appearance?view=netframework-4.8#fields).

As the docs suggest, this gives the radio buttons *the appearance of a Windows button.*

Answer (score 3):

Here is another idea for you - you can have one handler for all buttons like this:

[image]

An your code become very straightforward:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Enabled = true;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            button3.Enabled = true;
            button4.Enabled = true;

            Button btn = sender as Button;
            if (btn != null)
            {
                btn.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Why the down-vote here? Seems like a perfectly good solution to me.

Comment: @Enigmativity may be they didn't get my idea? Or it's just envy 

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to make the Button_Click a little less specific with the use of the some sort of data structure to control the buttons that you would like to group.

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Control the buttons.
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            buttons.Add(this.button1);
            buttons.Add(this.button2);
            buttons.Add(this.button3);
            buttons.Add(this.button4);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button button = sender as Button;
            foreach (var b in buttons)
            {
                if (button.Text.Equals(b.Text))
                {
                    b.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    b.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Button btn in Controls.OfType<Button>())
        btn.Enabled = true;
    Button button = sender as Button;
    button.Enabled = false;
}
```

dont forget to use System.Linq